# How to disable messages table 'xxx'. Scan count , logical reads , physical reads

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whenever I execute SQL query in SQL Server, there is a line inside a messages result window:

```
Messages Table 'xxx'. Scan count 1, logical reads 132, physical reads 0
```

The same as when statistics are turned on

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SELECT * FROM xxx
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

But even if only select is called?

```
SELECT * FROM xxx
```

Why is this? Previously there were no messages! Unless explicitly used. Can it be disabled?

Comment: ON and OFF seem to be used inverse in your example ...

Comment: the order is ok to turn stat on and after quey off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would most likely be a setting in your `SSMS`. Try to turn it off this way

Select from menu: Tools / Options / Query execution / SQL Server / Advanced

now uncheck the checkbox "`SET STATISTICS IO`"

No messages should be generated anymore